# close session in winform app after 5 seconds(idle) if no movement

Tags: c#, winforms, session

I am writing a c# Winform application and I need to close session if the computer is idle for 5 seconds. The application is like a restaurant application, when the waiter leaves his session open, I will close it after 5 seconds.

I found some code but I dont know how to use it and how to trigger it

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);   

internal struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;

    public uint dwTime;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I saw that link but I still dont know how to check every 5 sec

Comment: You need a `timer` also.

Comment: Run a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with 5-seconds interval and do your check in `Tick` event handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1- Add a `Timer` to your `Form`.

2- Set its interval property to 1000 (set it in `form_load` or in design mode from Properties window).

3-Add this method to your `Form` class.

```
public static uint GetIdleTime()
{
     LASTINPUTINFO LastUserAction = new LASTINPUTINFO();
     LastUserAction.cbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(LastUserAction);
     GetLastInputInfo(ref LastUserAction);
     return ((uint)Environment.TickCount - LastUserAction.dwTime);
}
```

4- in `Form_Load` start the timer:

`timer1.Start();`

5- in timer `tick` event check `GetIdleTime()`, for example if it is greater than `5000` means application was idled since 5 seconds ago.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GetIdleTime() > 5000)  
       Application.Exit();//For Example
}
```